# python unittests, do I need to import from the tests/__init__.py?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have my code organized like this:

base_project_dir/src
                /tests
                      /test1.py
                      /test2.py

in test1.py and test2.py I have the classes extending unittest.TestCase

according to python API doc, I should be able to run

python -m unittest tests   from base dir and run all tests.
but doing so shows that it finds 0 tests.  so I added 
from test1 import *
from test2 import *

into `tests/__init__.py`

now the above command works. but when I want to run individual tests, it sources the module **init**, which forcefully run all tests.

what is the correct way to organize this?

thanks
Yang

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your main project dir:

```
python -m unittest discover -v
```

This way you don't change the location for your relative imports. When you do `python -m unittest tests` it switches to this directory first and then can't import the projects code anymore.

Comment: thanks, but actually it still fails to find the dependency code in src, with the "discover" option

Comment: Do you have your local directory, the directory that you're running everything included in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: no, yes that would probably work. but it would be nice if python unittest would recognize a "conventional dir structure" like maven does, so that I don't have to set the pythonpath

Comment: I'm not a fan of unittest, too. I had a look at py.test a while ago, which has another quite different philosophy, which I liked a lot. It also has some basic support for unittest structures, so slow migration is possible, if you're using just simple unittest structures. Namely, setUpClass and runTest is not identified by itself currently. While runTest is not a big issue, just monkeypatch all unittest.TestCases on load with a wrapper from test_run to runTest, setUpClass would be more tricky, and would require some metaclass hackery I guess.